# Firebase analytics event date and timestamp aren't matching

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

Somehow event date and event_timestamp (1587831618755179) aren’t matching. Is this something from my end? Assuming both of the event properties have been set by firebase itself.

[image: !]

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Where is your app registered?

This is probably caused because of the timezone of this location. More specifically, in the [Firebase export schema description](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en), it is stated that in the field `event_date` you get *"The date on which the event was logged (YYYYMMDD format in the registered timezone of your app)"*.

For example, the data in your screenshot is valid for the regions of East Asia, Australia, New Zealand etc.